# Using SUMPRODUCT instead of SUMIFS

Tags: formula, reduction, sumproduct

I'm trying to reduce formula, but I really don't understand how to use the SUMPRODUCT function. I am a new excel user and doing things piece by piece.

I've tried using the SUM and SUMIFS function but it makes the formula so long and the file slow in reading the changes made.

`SUMIFS(OFFSET(INDEX('DAILY SALES'!$B:$B,MATCH(O$2,'DAILY SALES'!$B:$B,0)),2,7,15,1),OFFSET(INDEX('DAILY SALES'!$B:$B,MATCH(O$2,'DAILY SALES'!$B:$B,0)),2,5,15,1),$B5,OFFSET(INDEX('DAILY SALES'!$B:$B,MATCH(O$2,'DAILY SALES'!$B:$B,0)),2,6,15,1),DATA!$D$2),SUMIFS(OFFSET(INDEX('DAILY SALES'!$B:$B,MATCH(O$2,'DAILY SALES'!$B:$B,0)),2,12,15,1),OFFSET(INDEX('DAILY SALES'!$B:$B,MATCH(O$2,'DAILY SALES'!$B:$B,0)),2,10,15,1),$B5,
OFFSET(INDEX('DAILY SALES'!$B:$B,MATCH(O$2,'DAILY SALES'!$B:$B,0)),2,11,15,1),DATA!$F$2),SUMIFS(OFFSET(INDEX('DAILY SALES'!$B:$B,MATCH(O$2,'DAILY SALES'!$B:$B,0)),2,18,15,1),
OFFSET(INDEX('DAILY SALES'!$B:$B,MATCH(O$2,'DAILY SALES'!$B:$B,0)),2,16,15,1),$B5,OFFSET(INDEX('DAILY SALES'!$B:$B,MATCH(O$2,'DAILY SALES'!$B:$B,0)),2,17,15,1),DATA!$F$2),SUMIFS(OFFSET(INDEX('DAILY SALES'!$B:$B,MATCH(O$2,'DAILY SALES'!$B:$B,0)),2,23,15,1),OFFSET(INDEX('DAILY SALES'!$B:$B,MATCH(O$2,'DAILY SALES'!$B:$B,0)),2,21,15,1),$B5,OFFSET(INDEX('DAILY SALES'!$B:$B,MATCH(O$2,'DAILY SALES'!$B:$B,0)),2,22,15,1),DATA!$H$2))`

I expect the output to be at least 1/2 of the my given formula or if possible ,less. Thank you in advance.

1[This is where sales are recorded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQrIe.jpg)

2[When daily sales are recorded it is automatically deducted in inventory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72TH7.jpg)

The one that has the codes are the SOLD column. The sum of the QTY column of the retail, rebates and 25% are the ones being deducted.

I managed to reduce the Formula, but still working on reducing it more, here it is:

`=IF(INDEX('DAILY SALES'!$B:$B,MATCH(O$2,'DAILY SALES'!$B:$B,0)),SUM(
SUMPRODUCT(--(OFFSET(INDEX('DAILY SALES'!$B:$B,MATCH(O$2,'DAILY SALES'!$B:$B,0)),2,5,15,1)=$B5),--(OFFSET(INDEX('DAILY SALES'!$B:$B,MATCH(O$2,'DAILY SALES'!$B:$B,0)),2,6,15,1)=DATA!$D$2),OFFSET(INDEX('DAILY SALES'!$B:$B,MATCH(O$2,'DAILY SALES'!$B:$B,0)),2,7,15,1)),
SUMPRODUCT(--(OFFSET(INDEX('DAILY SALES'!$B:$B,MATCH(O$2,'DAILY SALES'!$B:$B,0)),2,10,15,1)=$B5),--(OFFSET(INDEX('DAILY SALES'!$B:$B,MATCH(O$2,'DAILY SALES'!$B:$B,0)),2,11,15,1)=DATA!$F$2),OFFSET(INDEX('DAILY SALES'!$B:$B,MATCH(O$2,'DAILY SALES'!$B:$B,0)),2,12,15,1)),
SUMPRODUCT(--(OFFSET(INDEX('DAILY SALES'!$B:$B,MATCH(O$2,'DAILY SALES'!$B:$B,0)),2,16,15,1)=$B5),--(OFFSET(INDEX('DAILY SALES'!$B:$B,MATCH(O$2,'DAILY SALES'!$B:$B,0)),2,17,15,1)=DATA!$F$2),OFFSET(INDEX('DAILY SALES'!$B:$B,MATCH(O$2,'DAILY SALES'!$B:$B,0)),2,18,15,1))))`

Comment: It might be more helpful if you actually give the data and the calculation you want to achieve over the data. You might even get a better way of doing what you want other than sumproduct. In the current format chances are that people might end up skipping the question as understanding that formula is too difficult

Comment: Thank you, I've added the images of the excel file.

Answer (score 0):

`=IF(INDEX('DAILY SALES'!$B:$B,MATCH(O$2,'DAILY SALES'!$B:$B,0)),
SUMPRODUCT(--('DAILY SALES'!G4:G18=$B5),--('DAILY SALES'!H4:H18=DATA!$D$2),'DAILY SALES'!I4:I18)+
SUMPRODUCT(--('DAILY SALES'!L4:L18=$B5),--('DAILY SALES'!M4:M18=DATA!$F$2),'DAILY SALES'!N4:N18)+
SUMPRODUCT(--('DAILY SALES'!R4:R18=$B5),--('DAILY SALES'!S4:S18=DATA!$F$2),'DAILY SALES'!T4:T18)+
SUMPRODUCT(--('DAILY SALES'!W4:W18=$B5),--('DAILY SALES'!X4:X18=DATA!$H$2),'DAILY SALES'!Y4:Y18))`

This is the shortest I can get, however, I lose functionality of just extending everything to the last day of the year.